# Business English: contracted forum?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, collocation

I would like to know your opinions regarding the use of the term "contracted forum".

The context is a long-term project for which steering committee meetings are being conducted. At one time, the meetings would all follow the same format, and include the same representatives. However, a decision was reached, under which there would be alternating sessions - an "expanded/extended session", which would include a wider representation and participation, and more subjects covered, and a "contracted session (?)", which would involve less participants, and be dedicated to a handful of topics.

Is "expanded/contracted" the correct adjective to use? Are there any better alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use the following:

an ***[open](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/open) session:***

> - acessible to all; unrestricted as to participants.

and a ***[restricted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/restricted) session:***

> - confined; limited.
> - available only to authorized persons.

The Free Dictionary